# How to transfer files from Phone to PC using ADB?

Tags: adb

Location of pictures:

`/storage/sdcard0/pictures/screenshots/`

I want to move all the screenshots to below folder in my PC

`C:\Users\[username]\Downloads`

I have ADB enabled and not rooted my phone.

Help me to use ADB pull.

Comment: try this 
cmd = "adb pull /storage/sdcard0/pictures/screenshots/* \"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\"";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command:

`adb pull /storage/sdcard0/pictures/screenshots/ C:\Users\<username>\Downloads`

You will find the folder named 'screenshots' at the location `C:\Users\<username>\Downloads`